# Azure workspace-based Log Analytics logLevel being ignored

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I have a c# vs 6 function app. I use workspace-based Log Analytics. I am trying to turn off logging I don't need in my host.json file.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logging": {
      "logLevel": {
        "default": "Warning",
        "Function": "Warning",
        "Host.Aggregator": "Error",
        "Host.Results": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "Worker": "Error"
      },
      "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 10,
          "excludedTypes": "Dependency;PageView;Event"
        },
        "enableLiveMetrics": true,
        "enableDependencyTracking": false,
        "enablePerformanceCountersCollection": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I look in the Logs in Log Analytics there are recent records in `AppDependencies` and Informational messages in AppTraces (query `AppTraces | where SeverityLevel < 2`)

Why are my data being ingested when I have asked them to be turned off, and how do I get the data have I asked to be excluded not to be ingested?

Answer (score 0):

I had it the wrong way around. I set initialSamplingPercentage to zero and excluded things I **wanted** from the sampling.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
    "logging": {
      "logLevel": {
        "default": "Warning",
        "Function": "Warning",
        "Host.Aggregator": "Error",
        "Host.Results": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "Worker": "Error"
      },
      "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
          "isEnabled": true,
          "initialSamplingPercentage": 0,
          "excludedTypes": "Trace;Exception"
        },
        "enableLiveMetrics": false,
        "enableDependencyTracking": false,
        "enablePerformanceCountersCollection": false,
        "httpAutoCollectionOptions": {
          "enableHttpTriggerExtendedInfoCollection": false,
          "enableW3CDistributedTracing": false,
          "enableResponseHeaderInjection": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```